# How to structure SQL database for multiple types of users and roles

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm building a db for a site where brands can create a storefront and also create staff accounts to manage said storefront.

They'll also be customers who aren't associated with a brand whatsoever that can purchase from any brand.

My question is, how should I properly set up tables to have a `customer` user and also `brand`/`brand_users` users that manage the store?

edit: i also suppose `brand` is not a user, more of something a user creates

Here's what I've got so far in terms of db tables:
[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me. Is there a specific issue your current structure isn't handling correctly?

Comment: Can you describe what SQL statements you mean by "manage the store"?